# Arcpy hanging on Linux

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcpy, linux

I am having issues getting arcpy to run correctly on Linux Red Hat.  I solved some earlier problems which appeared to be related to permissions on the init_server file.  Now that si resolved, when I 'import arcpy' in Python, it just hangs, not even timing out after 20 minutes.

Does anyone have any experience of using arcpy on Linux and did you face any issues setting it up?

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

**EDIT**

AN update.  I have rebooted the server and edited the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in init_server.sh and also changed the call to set_pyton_anv.sh (as it didn' appear to be calling it ) and it failed with **Cannot open X display "(not specified)"**  I then started an XWindows session on the box in Hummingbird and then, and only then, did import arcpy run correctly.

Not really sure what to say other than **What?  Why?  How?**

Does anybody know any reason why this should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, we did get around it by building aheadless Xwin session. The root user is a bit of a red herring as you can do it without. There are two files 'init_server.sh and 'set_python_env' which need properly configuring too; we call the headless XWin session in there.